# Apache POI Formula Evaluator not computing cell containing formula

Tags: excel, apache-poi, evaluation

I have an excel file that has formulas in some cells and some input fields based on which value is being computed in the Formula Cell.

After setting the values in the respective cells using apache poi `setCellValue()` **The Values are being set in the excel. This part is working**. Then I am running

```
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
evaluator.evaluate(cell);
```

where the cell is the place where I have the formula and also it has some pre-computed value.

My problem was that, after running the `FormulaEvaluator` when I am fetching the cell value using `cell.getNumericCellValue()` it is fetching me the pre-computed or older cell value instead of new computed values from the new values set in the cells.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're expecting another behaviour than the method provides:

> *Using FormulaEvaluator.evaluate(Cell cell)*
>
> This evaluates a given cell, and returns the new value, without affecting the cell

You might want to check if `evaluateFormulaCell` or `evaluateInCell` better fit your requirements.

See also the documentation at http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval.html

Comment: If I use evaluateFormulaCell or evaluateInCell then I get a error that  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a ERROR cell`

Comment: What output do you get when debugging the calls as described at the end of the docs page in the link? Also what is the result of your original call to `evaluate`? `evaluator` should contain the respective result. If this already produces an error the issue might be that POI simply can't evaluate the formula in its current form.

Comment: Thanks Markus, I did same small silly mistake was able to resolve it by call appropriate getStringCellValue(), apparently it was generating String that was why it was giving this warning!!